# Slick slider uneven height

Tags: slick.js

I'm trying to create a slick slider. I was able to create it properly using images with the same height and width. But the issue now is when I try to upload an image who's height is smaller or larger than the rest of the image. Below is how it look

[image]

Below is the initialization I used to construct the slider

```
$sliderWrapper
.on('init', function (event, slick) {
    $sliderWrapper.addClass('slick-slider-init');
})
.slick({
    accessibility: true,                    
    arrows: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 600,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
    centerMode: true,                    
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 1501,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 2
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 901,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 2
        }
    }, {
        breakpoint: 601,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1,
            arrows: false
        }
    }]
});
```

Any idea on how to fix this? Would really appreciate your help on this

Update:

Here is my HTML markup. I'm using .net cshtml file format

```
<div class="related-products">
    <h6 class="h6 text-center header__title">@Model.Title</h6>
    <div class="related-products__inner">
        @foreach (var product in Model.RelatedProducts)
        {
            <div class="product-item product-item--link">
                <div class="product-item__inner">
                    <img src="@product.Image.Url" alt="@product.Image.Name" class="product-item__image" />                                   
                    <div class="related-product__details">
                        <div class="details__content">
                            <div class="product-item__description header__title">@product.Line1</div>
                            <div class="product-item__title">
                                <span>@product.Name</span>     <span>@product.Line2</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cta__container">
                                <a href="@product.Url" class="cta light-brown"><span class="cta__label">Discover</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>                           
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please share your html code

Comment: @DixitSavaliya update my question and included the HTML markup. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
 In Your CSS File

.product-item__inner {
 height:
 width: 
} 

.product-item__inner img {
 max-height:100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 min-height:100%;
 min-width:100%;
 object-fit:cover;
}
```